# Search all untranslated text strings in PHP and HTML files

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework, localization, translation

I have this upcomming task of translating an entire website. The website is partially translated, meaning it utilizes the translation features of ZendFramework (v1).

Translations are stored in array based language files like this: [en.php]

```
<?php
return array(

// Language Config
'config_LanguageDirection' => 'ltr',

// Site wide translations
'site_name' => 'My site',
'site_slogan' => 'Le slogan',

'site_keywords' => 'key is the words',
'site_description' => 'Yada yada yada',

'header_logo_img_alt' => 'My site',         
'fat_footer_company_details' => 'Trivial copyright information',        

'company_name' => 'UnoBambino',
);
```

**Is there a script in PHP or Bash/Shell, that can search all directories and find untranslated strings?**

I'm thinking

- text in html attributes like 'alt' and 'title'
- text between html tags
- text in PHP code, which would usually be between single and double quotes.
- not text that are used in a function _('like this') or _("like this") - which are considered already translated.
- other types that i haven't thought upon

3rd party software would also be of interest, if it gets the job done.

Comment: You can collect all the untranslated scripts and then run multiple `grep -rin <pattern> <folder path>` http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep to locate all the places that does contain/does not contain (see patterns) some string

Comment: There is a very cheap device called "an intern" that we generally use to search for tedious things like this. If you cannot acquire this device then I'm afraid you're going to have to do it yourself.